# load mat files into matlab and use variables later in the .m file

Tags: matlab, matlab-load

I only want to load some of the variables from a lot of.mat files (a1.mat, a2.mat.....) into the .m file, and use them as function. Here is my code

```
files=dir('a*.mat'); 
numfiles=length(files);

for k=1:numfiles
filename=files(k).name;
data=load(filename,'Name','Age','Country');
end

data_jan_name=[data.Name]
```

However, it always returns an error message:

```
??? Undefined variable "data" or function "data.Name".
```

Answer (score 0):

This all looks good. I would check that it is actually running through the for loop. Let it print out file name. Otherwise, perhaps those Variables `Name, Age and Country` don't exist in the files, so maybe let it print data as well.

If you show us what a regular a.mat file looks like I can expand on this answer.